# How to make a function that calls aand prints each students name and courses

Tags: python

Here is what i have so far

```
from CSE_324_course import Course
from CSE_324_skeleton_student import Student

math = Course("Algebra I")
language = Course("Spanish I")
science = Course("Earth Science")
history = Course("U.S. History I")
phys_ed = Course("Physical Education I")
speaking = Course("Speech I")
art = Course("Art I")

test_student = Student("Jill", "Sample")

test_student.add_course(math)
test_student.add_course(language)
 test_student.add_course(science)
test_student.add_course(history)

test_student2 = Student("Bill", "Sample")

test_student2.add_course(math)
test_student2.add_course(phys_ed)
test_student2.add_course(science)
test_student2.add_course(history)

test_student3 = Student("Kim", "Sample")

test_student3.add_course(language)
test_student3.add_course(speaking)
test_student3.add_course(science)
test_student3.add_course(art)

student_list=[test_student,test_student2,test_student3]

for (test_student,test_student2,test_student3 : get_course)
if (test_student().equals(search))
 System.out.println(teststudnetgetCourse());


#Each iteration should:
    #get,concatenate, and print the first and last name of the student
    #print all courses for that student
    #print a blank line between students
```

'''for this part you may need to review the other skeleton code to:
        - see how to get items from a list
        - see if there is code (like a function) in that file you can call in this file
        - verify that running this file gets you the correct output with information from that file
    Also, review syntax of pulling items from a list f

2 page of code
    Course import Course

```
class Student:

student_id = 0

def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
    self.first_name = first_name
    self.last_name = last_name
    self.courses = []
    self.student_id = Student.student_id
    Student.student_id += 1

def __str__(self):


    # TODO You will need to use a variable in the loop, so you must intialize it here,
    # that variable will need to be initalized to get items listed in the first def _init_ section
    # TODO add a loop that will go through the course list
        # TODO Add code here to create a string representation of a student,
        # including first and last name and all courses that student is taking
    return "complete this return statement based on your in loop variable"

def get_first_name(self):
    return self.first_name

def get_last_name(self):
    return self.last_name

def get_student_id(self):
    return self.student_id

def add_course(self, new_course):
    # TODO add code to append new_course to self.courses
    print "Course not yet added, implementation needed."
```

3rd page
    class Course:

```
    def __init__(self, course_name):
        self.course_name = course_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name
```

Comment: `System.out.println(teststudnetgetCourse());`? This looks like Java.

Comment: Anyway, the code formatting is off. The easiest way to format is to copy and paste directly from your text-editor, then highlight the text you've pasted into StackOverflow and press ctrl-K

Comment: The `for (test_student,test_student2,test_student3 : get_course)` looks very Java-ish, too. Regardless, `student_list` is a list, so asking how to "make a function student_list` doesn't really make sense. Please [edit] your question an clear-up these matters.

Comment: I'm a beginner at python and what I'm really trying to do is call a function that prints each student name and courses their taking

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to change

```
for (test_student,test_student2,test_student3 : get_course)
    if (test_student().equals(search))
        System.out.println(teststudnetgetCourse());
```

(which you have improperly indented) to:

```
for student in student_list:
    print("{} {}".format(student.first_name, student.last_name))
    for course in student.courses:
        print(course) # This won't work because "2 page of code Course import Course" needs to be finished
    print("\n") # blank line between students
```

Comment: thanks do you have ay suggestion to how  could change it so that it works.

Comment: @KanyA Yeah, finish your other script where `# TODO add code to append new_course to self.courses`;`print "Course not yet added, implementation needed."` You could make it `self.courses.append(str(new_course))`